# Is it possible to reuse the tf::TransformBroadcaster

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is simple as mentioned above. Is it possible to reuse the object `br` for multiple transforms having **different** parent and child frames

```
static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
        br.sendTransform( tf::StampedTransform(tf, ros::Time::now(), "frame_1", "frame_2") );
        br.sendTransform( tf::StampedTransform(tf, ros::Time::now(), "frame_2", "frame_3") );
```

The question popped reading the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

Furthermore where should I start looking when the terminal erros me [nan_input](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained) for the send transform, assuming the quaternion is fine, a normalized unit quaternion.

```
tf::Quaternion q_f2tof3(rot[3], rot[4], rot[5], qw);
tf::Transform(q_f2tof3, tf::Vector3(0,0,0))
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234500/is-it-possible-to-reuse-the-tf::transformbroadcaster/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it's fine to reuse the `TransformBroadcaster` to send multiple different transforms, irrespective of their relationship. Based on your above content you may want to send them simultaneously [using a vector of transforms](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1TransformBroadcaster.html#a5c4e60697cb3109427fed45904673d44).

A nan_input almost always means an unnormalized quaternion. The other option is that you're passing in a nan value to the vector. But based on the above snippet that does not look possible and as such I'd suggest checking your normalization logic.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2